# How to call malloc() in Android's ndk-gdb

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

When I try to call the malloc() function in ndk-gdb

```
(gdb) call malloc(4)
```

the gdb report failed

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x4017a8f4 in ?? () from /Users/chyhfj/Desktop/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/linker
```

And a error log appear in log view:

```
F/linker  (32355): ERROR: malloc called from the dynamic linker!
```

I do some research, look into android bionic linker [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/linker/linker.cpp#L171), and found it implements malloc() function to avoid calling malloc() in the linker.

```
// You shouldn't try to call memory-allocating functions in the dynamic linker.
// Guard against the most obvious ones.
#define DISALLOW_ALLOCATION(return_type, name, ...) \
    return_type name __VA_ARGS__ \
    { \
        const char* msg = "ERROR: " #name " called from the dynamic linker!\n"; \
        __libc_format_log(ANDROID_LOG_FATAL, "linker", "%s", msg); \
        write(2, msg, strlen(msg)); \
        abort(); \
    }
DISALLOW_ALLOCATION(void*, malloc, (size_t u __unused));
DISALLOW_ALLOCATION(void, free, (void* u __unused));
DISALLOW_ALLOCATION(void*, realloc, (void* u1 __unused, size_t u2 __unused));
DISALLOW_ALLOCATION(void*, calloc, (size_t u1 __unused, size_t u2 __unused));
```

and I check the loaded shared library:

```
(gdb) info shared library
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x40175a40  0x40180da8  Yes (*)     /Users/chyhfj/Desktop/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/linker
0x400feac0  0x4012e36c  Yes (*)     /Users/chyhfj/Desktop/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
```

The `linker` and `libc.so` both loaded.

---

Updated: As [Richard MA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24506545/502836) references some gdb commands, here is some more infomations

```
(gdb) info functions malloc
0x40177664  malloc
0x400ffb58  malloc

(gdb) info symbol malloc
malloc in section .text of /Users/chyhfj/Desktop/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/linker
(gdb) info symbol 0x40177664
malloc in section .text of /Users/chyhfj/Desktop/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/linker
(gdb) info symbol 0x400ffb58
malloc in section .text of /Users/chyhfj/Desktop/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/libc.so
```

---

This broken things I want to do:

- Under gdb, I can't call any function that internally calls malloc()

So, The question:

Why the gdb call the `malloc()` function that implements in `linker` instead of `libc.so`,

And how should I do to call the `libc.so`'s `malloc()`, also the functions which  internally calls `malloc()`

Answer (score 3):

### Example:

```
(gdb) info symbol malloc
malloc in section .text of /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

(gdb) info addr malloc
Symbol "malloc" is at 0x7ffff7df07a0 in a file compiled without debugging.
```

The prototype of malloc is: `void *malloc(size_t size)`

then, cast the pointer

```
(gdb) x (void (*)(size_t))(0x7ffff7df07a0)(4)
0x603030:   0x00000000
```

`0x6003030` is the result

Comment: Great! but doing so every time it's panic, also the functions which internally calls malloc() still broken.